# How to access the values of the fields in a Firestore Subcollection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database looks like this:

[image: Picture]

How can I access the values of the fields shown in the "Green area" when I don't have the Collection name of the "Red area"?

- How can I loop through "red area" collections to find all of them with field "RequestStatus" equal to "Completed"?

Comment: Instead of describing what you **don't** know, edit your question to show what you **do** know? I.e. if there are dozens of friends with hundreds of friendship statuses, what determines what status(es) to return from which friend(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not retrieve document value without collection. So i suggest change the Collection name to Friendship status. Then you can easily retrieve fields of documents.

It needs to be like this :

```
FriendShip

---->Current User id

     --->Friendship Status

         -----> Document id
```

Then you can use [orderby](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) or [Equalto](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) Function.

Code for above structure.

```
mfirebaseFirestore.collection("Friendship").document(mCurrentUser).collection("FriendshipStatus")
                .whereEqualTo("RequestStatus", "Completed")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d("abc", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("abc", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Note :

`Whereequalto` is worked when you trying to find data in collection. So you have to query till collection. Then use `whereequalto` to documents similar to your query

Comment: I will try this out and let you know from here, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

As presented in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document), there is no way to list the subcollection of a document **with the Client SDKs** (Android, iOS, Web).

On the other hand, "the `getCollections()` method of the Cloud Firestore **server client libraries** lists all subcollections of a document reference".

Since it seems you are using the Android SDK, you need to find a work around. One possible workaround is to save the sub-collection names in a dedicated a field in the parent document. For example you could use an Array field for storing all the names of the subcollection.

You would normally populate this field when you create the first document of a subcollection, using the Android SDK.

In case, for any reason, you cannot do that from the client, you could use a Cloud Function, which relies on the Admin SDK and therefore can use the `getCollections()` method referred to above.